# PHP universal delete file

Tags: php, файловая-система, delete

Какие могут быть недостатки у кода ниже ?

Предоставление удаления файла передаётся через заранее включённый shell в файловую систему OS

```
// universal delete file and dirs (Windows, Other os)
function DeleteFileString(string $file) {
    if(is_file($file = strOsSlesh($file))) {
        return unlink($file);
    } elseif(is_dir($file)) {
        return (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '\\') ?
            `rd /S /q $file` // Windows delele all files
        :   `rm -rf  $file`; // Other os delele all files
    }
    return false;
}
```

Плюсы в том, что работает на много быстрее всего, что есть из штатных известных возможностей

```
[php] => 7.3.4
[DeleteFileString] => 5.343348
[IteratorDeleteDir] => 11.705709
[scandirDelete] => 11.533627
[globDelete] => 13.708378
[opendirDelete] => 11.481467
)
```

https://pastebin.com/8XQLqt4K

Comment: Что если попытаться удалить папку с названием `1;rm -rf *`

Comment: @andreymal `is_dir` не пройдет

Comment: вы уверены, что обратный слэш надо эскейпить в одинарных кавычках?

Comment: @teran ну так создать такую папку, чтоб прошло :)

Comment: @teran Да, совершенно уверен. Это особенности экранирования

Answer (score 0):

Если PHP или Shell через который вы выполняете данные команды - не имеет root прав, тогда это вполне безопасно для самой системы. 
Но не совсем безопасно для конкретного пользователя, если он может удалить свои же директории которые как-то критично влияют на работу сайта. 
Я думаю, желательно как-то контролировать пути для удаления, например установить такое ограничение:

> если файлы для конкретного пользователя лежат в папке
>   /home/user_name, тогда от юзера принимать только /path_to_file и уже
>   внути скрипта складывать в кучу: /home/user_name/path_to_file